# Gerrit always updates parent unmerged commit patchset

Tags: gerrit

This issue has been puzzling me for quite sometime now, please help.

Two teams have been working on a project developing 2 submodules:

1. Team 1: Develops submodule 1 and does a commit and raises a gerrit, say, 233421 (which is **UNMERGED**, in code review)
2. Team 2: Does cherrypick of submodule 1 with id 233421, and does a commit of submodule 2 and pushes (gerrit id say 233422)

In step2 above, along with creating a new patchset (233422) for submodule 2, it also updates the cherrypicked patchset 233421.

How to force stop to not update cherrypicked patchset and only create a SINGLE new gerrit with submodule 2's changes in it?

Comment: Please explain what "updates the cherrypicked patchset 233421" means. Show the Git commands you have used.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira it means that 233421 get's a new patchset. This happens because when Team 2 cherry-picked 233421 they ended up with a new commit (a distinct ref) that had the same Change Id. When they push 233422 gerrit gets both the commit they intended to push and it's parent... which looks to gerrit like a new patchset on 233421. FWIW, I am also interested in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not cherry-pick an unmerged change and use it as a base for a new change. If you really want to do that, you can change the Chante-Id of the new commit created after the cherry-pick, so Gerrit will create a new change for it, instead of updating the original one. I don't think this process is the best but it'll solve the issue you're talking about.